# PHP 7.2 does htmlentities automatically?

Tags: php, iis, html-entities

I just installed PHP 7.2 for testing and I found a strange thing. After form submission or query the special characters are replaced automatically with HTML entities. Does PHP 7 do this automatically or is there a setting in the php.ini? Or maybe it's an IIS thing? Can't find aníthing on google or stackoverflow.

Anyway PHP.ini charset is set to ISO-8859-1 if that matters.

Example:

```
input value = "éáűőúüó"

$_GET["input"] = "éá&#369;&#337;úüó"
```

Thanks whoever knows what's up!

Comment: How do you output the string? Is `$_GET["input"] === "éá&#369;&#337;úüó"` true?

Comment: The browser converts all of that

Comment: `with htmlspecialchars -> éá&#369;&#337;úüó`
`var_dump -> string(17) "éáűőúüó"`, so the string éáűőúüó is clearly not 17 chars long

Comment: PHP isn't; the browser is. You can check this with Firebug or a
sniffer.

Comment: zaman sandhu: you are saying the browser does that? I understand if it's in the URL but why does this replace if I use POST?